# How can I assign a variable from one JavaScript file to other JS File?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Please look at the sample scenario, 
Say I have a variable called,
`var myvariable;`

Then in another JavaScript file I assign the value to varaiable,

```
myvariable = "Hi";
```

**What I tried?**

Basically, what I did for this is the newPassword variable in Firebase's [custom-email-handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler). I have another page where you reset your password but I have the script where it changes the password in another JavaScript file.

Comment: Have you loaded the scripts into a document, or do you want to do this on a file level only?

Comment: I could load the scripts into a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `myvariable` is in the global scope, meaning it is not enclosed in any function, then it will be available to all other scripts by default.  And, frustratingly enough, if you DO declare it inside another function, but forget to use "var" when declaring it, it will also end up in the global scope.

#### Consider this:

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

script1.js:

```
var myvariable = "hi";
```

script2.js:

```
console.log(myvariable);
// "hi"
```

When the page loads, "hi" will be printed to console, because `script1.js` was listed first

#### As opposed to this:

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

script1.js:

```
function() {
    var myvariable = "hi";
}
```

script2.js:

```
console.log(myvariable);
// Uncaught ReferenceError: myvariable is not defined
```

When the page loads, script2.js will throw an error, because it can't see `myvariable`, since it is locked inside a function scope.

#### One last case

```
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

script1.js:

```
var myFunc = function() {
    //notice I'm not going to use "var" in front of myvariable
    myvariable = "hi";
}
//As soon as you call the function, myvariable is now global. Oops!
myFunc();
```

script2.js:

```
console.log(myvariable);
// "hi"
```

If you want to know more about this subject, just search "javascript scope", "javascript global scope", or "javascript implicit global".

And, to address what I think was your original point of confusion, just remember that all scripts are run in the context of the browser window. There's no concept of "how do I make this script talk to that script?". To help visual how it works, imagine taking the contents of your scripts and dumping it in one large script file. That's conceptually what happens after the browser is finished loading everything, (barring advanced topics like asynchronous loading)

Answer (score 0):

You should make it global by adding it to the window object.

script1.js

```
window.myvariable="Hi";
```

script2.js

```
alert(myvariable);
```

Note that script1.js will have to load first.